# Return node ID along with complete node

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and working on spring data Neo4J repositories. I want to fetch all the nodes with all property values and node ID. Something like

```
{name: 'sid',age: 20, id: 123}
```

One option is to have following query

```
match (e: Employee) return {name: e.name, age: e.age, id: ID(e)}
```

But the problem here is I have to explicitly add all the properties in the JSON definition. Else can do following, but this gives me nested object and not a flat object

```
match (e: Employee) return {obj: e, id: ID(e)}
```

Can some help me with this?

Edit: Actual query is more complex with more than two different node labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no way with the current Cypher syntax to create a flat map with all the properties of `e` plus an extra `id` property.

But there is a workaround that you may consider acceptable (or overkill). And that is to add the `id` property to every `Employee` node at creation time. This has to be done in a `SET` clause, as the ID of the new node is not available within a `CREATE` clause. For example:

```
CREATE (e:Employee {name: "Fred", age: 42})
SET e.id = ID(e)
```

That way, your `MATCH` query can be extremely simple:

```
MATCH (e: Employee)
RETURN e;
```